# Change a column in mysql db to an md5 encryption

Tags: phpmyadmin

someone suggest the query below to me, i tired it, but didn't work.

SELECT student SET password = MD5(TRIM(SUBSTR(@row, 12, 22))), ;

i uploaded a csv file from phpmyadmin to a db name student,the password filed has data like a string in them (mypassword). How do i run a query in mysql to change all the student password to an md5 encryption?

Comment: Use this way to update password : UPDATE student SET PASSWORD=MD5('22222');

Comment: Thanks a million.......it works.

Comment: please how do i go about that?

Comment: just upvote now

Comment: @AlfredJoseph - you should be able to click on the tick from Sanjays answer below (and then click the up button to upvote too)

Comment: Upvote answer , not comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way to update password :

```
UPDATE student SET PASSWORD=MD5('22222');
```